# Custom resolution doesn't add to display

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, display, resolution

I'm trying to add custom resolution to display, but it won't add.

What I've tried so far :

**1-firstly see my current resolutuins**

```
$ xrandr
```

The output :

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       60.0     59.8  
   1152x864       60.0  
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384        60.0     59.8  
   640x480        59.9  
   576x432        60.1  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        72.2     60.3     56.3  
   320x240        60.1  
TV-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

**2- trying to generate a "modeline" by using cvt (1280x768)**

```
$ cvt 1280 768 60
```

The output:

```
  # 1280x768 59.87 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.78 kHz; pclk: 79.50 MHz
  Modeline "1280x768_60.00"   79.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

**3- Now tell this to xrandr :**

```
$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1280x768_60.00"   79.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

4- **Finally :**

```
$ sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-0 "1280x768_60.00"
```

The output :

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

After I did all above steps, again :

```
$ xrandr
```

The output :

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       60.0     59.8  
   1152x864       60.0  
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384        60.0     59.8  
   640x480        59.9  
   576x432        60.1  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        72.2     60.3     56.3  
   320x240        60.1  
TV-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1280x768_60.00 (0x27b)   79.5MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock   47.8KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock   59.9Hz
```

As you can see my custom resolution(1280x768) doesn't added!

Any helps would be great.

Comment: Same problem (Ubuntu v22.04.3): https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQFxI.png. Help!